# How can evaluate (int*) % int?

Tags: c

I am implementing a circular queue, when the queue is full, I want that the pointer return to first of array address.

```
struct Sample{

    void* ptr;
};

int main() {

    char a[20] = "hello";

    struct Sample sample;

    sample.ptr = (a + 2) % 6;

    printf("%s\n", sample.ptr);

}
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error:

> `invalid operands to binary % (have ’char* ’ and ‘int’)`

I know the problem is from `%` , for example if I change line 12 to `sample.ptr = (a + 2)` it will work. But I need to evaluate `%`. How can I do this?

Comment: Just what do you expect the modulus operator to *do* on a pointer?

Comment: And you title doesn't match what you are doing.

Comment: I am implementing a circular queue, when the queue is full, I want that the pointer return to first of array address

Comment: Then you would be better off using array syntax `a[i]` where `i` is computed as `some_integer_expression % queue_length`.

Comment: If it were allowed, it would give you an address between 0 and 5, which isn't very useful.

Comment: @samansamani you should describe what you're trying to do in the question.

Comment: I like arrays more than pointers, but the problem is that I'm implementing a circular queue on shared memory in Linux, and shared memory only works with pointer

Comment: I tried  `sample.ptr[2 % 6]`  but it has syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

```
sample.ptr = (a + 2) % 6;
```

`a` is a `char*` (i.e. a memory address), adding 2 to it is ok - this will point 2 `chars` further in memory.

But doing a `%` (modulus) (even if it worked) will of course create an invalid pointer.

`sample.ptr` would be pointing somewhere to memory address 0 to 5 (0 being the `NULL pointer`), which is probably not what you want.

**Update**:

> I am implementing a circular queue, when the queue is full, I want
>   that the pointer return to first of array address

**To implement a circular queue**, you can use:

```
sample.ptr = a + (pos % number_of_items_in_array); // brackets not really needed
```

Or:

```
sample.ptr = &a[pos % number_of_items_in_array];
```

`sample.ptr` should also be a `char*`, not a `void*`:

```
struct Sample{
    char* ptr;
};
```

Comment: Don't know if it'd be worth adding an example of what a pointer mod 6 would look like, just to reinforce why it's wrong?

Comment: @samansamani What solution? There isn't any reason describing why you need this in the question itself.

Comment: See updated answer (based on extra comment from OP).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to implement a circular queue, you want to use the modulus operator on the index of the array, not the address of the array:

```
sample.ptr = a + (2 % 6);
```

In this case, the index `2` happens to be a constant, but you can put any value there and `ptr` would point to somewhere between a[0] and a[5].

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, using array syntax is cleaner:

```
sample.ptr = &a[2 % 6];
```

Because `ptr` is defined as a `void *`, you can't use array syntax, since the element size is not known.  You could change the definition to `char *` which would allow this syntax to work.

Comment: Alternatively and more readable imo.  `sample.ptr = &a[2 % 6]`

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a as an array rather than a pointer and increment index, the modolo will work

```
a[index++] = new_value;
index %= maxindex;
```

This should allow your loop to work and cause the index to rotate properly.
You can set sample.ptr as &a[index] explicitly.